# Show $D_3\cong S_3$ and $D_n\ncong S_n$ for $n\gt 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

> Show that $D_3\cong S_3$ and $D_n\ncong S_n$ for $n\gt 3$, where $D_3$ denotes the dihedral group of order 6 and $S_3$ the symmetric group.

I define a group isomorphism between $D_3$ and $S_3$. Both group have $6$ elements, the dihedral group is the symmetric group of an equilateral triangle.

Let the vertices $$P_k = (\cos(\frac{2(k-1)\pi}{3}), \sin(\frac{2(k-1)\pi}{3})),\qquad k=1,2,3.$$

I define a group isomorphism $\varphi:D_3\to S_3, f\mapsto \sigma(f)$, where $\sigma(f)$ are the permutation of the vertices defined by $f$.

E.g. for $r\in D_3$ the rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is the permutation $\sigma(r)=(1 2 3)$.

If I can show that no two rotations define the same permutation, it follows that $\varphi$ is a bijection and I'm finished. How can I show that? Also, how do I show that $D_n\ncong S_n$ for $n\gt 3$? Is there a good counterexample?

Comment: For $n>3$ just notice that $|D_n| = 2n$ and $|S_n| = n!$

Comment: @Mathmo123 right, thanks!

Comment: you mean equilateral triangle, not isosceles.

Comment: Beyond OP's scope: $D_m\cong S_n\iff m=n=3$. So, for instance, $D_{12}\ncong S_4$ (although they both have order $24$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n = 3$, take $\sigma$ = (123), $\tau$  = (12).

Then $\tau^2 = e = \sigma^3$, and $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (12)(123)(12) = (132) = \sigma^{-1}$ so $S_3$ is dihedral.

Answer (score 2):

$D_n$ has $2n$ elements while $S_n$ has $n!$ elements. These are different if $n>3$.